# C# Which one to use when request has object input? HTTPGET request using '[FromQuery]' attribute or HTTPPOST request

Tags: c#, rest, httprequest, asp.net-apicontroller

We have a request like '[HttpGet("GetAllDtoWithSearch")]'. Despite being a GET request, it takes a DTO(object) using the [FromQuery] attribute. However, the URL for the request, 'https://localhost:123456/api/ControllerName/GetAllDtoWithSearch?customerName=blabla&comment=thisIsaComment', becomes longer as it includes all the parameters present in the DTO(object).

For GET requests that involve multiple parameters and are designed for retrieval, is it appropriate to use [FromQuery], or should we make the HTTP request a POST and send it that way?

The URL for the POST request is:
https://localhost:123456/api/ControllerName/GetAllDtoWithSearch

We use both of these two at different requests. But which one is appropriate in general apis.

Comment: A general rule of thumb is: Use `GET` requests if you want retrieve some data from the backend but you don't want to create or modify data. Use `POST` if you want create new data. But that's just a general rule of thumb. If you have a lot of parameters to transfer with the request, there is nothing wrong in using a post instead. On the other hand there is also nothing wrong with having (reasonably) long Url. (Chrome for instance limits the length of an URL to ~2MB). It's your API, do whatever seems fit.

Comment: Your question can not really be answered. As you noted yourself, both approaches work from a technical point of view. Any 'answer' given will only be an opinion. To give you mine: if its a RESTful api, I'd stick with the GET. For a RPC-api I wouldn't care at all